# Number of Cycles from list of values, which are mix of positives and negatives in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

**Have an RDD with List of values, which are mix of positives and negatives.
Need to compute number of cycles from this data.**

For example,

`val range = List(sampleRange(2020,2030,2040,2050,-1000,-1010,-1020,Starting point,-1030,2040,-1020,2050,2040,2020,end point,-1060,-1030,-1010)`

the interval between each value in above list is 1 second. ie., 2020 and 2030 are recorded in 1 second interval and so on.

how many times it turns from negative to positive and stays positive for >= 2 seconds.
If >= 2 seconds it is a cycle.

**Number of cycles: Logic**
**Example 1:** List(1,2,3,4,5,6,-15,-66)
No. of cycles is **1**.
Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 6th element, we had 5 intervals which means 5 seconds. So one cycle. 
As we move to 6th element of list, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 6th element and move to 7th element. The negative values are only 2 and interval is only 1. So not counted as cycle.
**Example 2:**
List(11,22,33,-25,-36,-43,20,25,28)
No. of cycles is **3**.
Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 3rd element, we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle As we move to 4th element of list, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 4th element and move to 5th, 6th element. we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle As we move to 7th element of list, it is a positive value. So we start counting from 7th element and move to 8th, 9th element. we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle.

*range* is a RDD in the use case. It looks like
scala> range
range: Seq[com.Range] = List(XtreamRange(858,890,899,920,StartEngage,-758,-790,-890,-720,920,940,950))

Comment: Looks like there should be on cycle here right `-1020,2050,2040,2020,` ?

Comment: Its a sample data. The values in the list are random there is not pattern as such. val range = list(17850,17860,17859,17870,-17860,-17859,-17870,2020,2030,2040,2050,-1000,-1010,-1020,-1030,2040,-1020,2050,2040,2020,-1060,-1030,-1010)

Comment: Is a cycle always going to be defined as being positive for two seconds? Or might this vary?

Comment: Also, in your real use case, `range` is a `RDD`, right? Not  `List`? That might change things

Comment: Number of cycles: Logic
Example 1: 
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,-15,-66) 
No. of cycles is 1. 
Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 6th element, we had 5 intervals which means 5 seconds. So one cycle.
As we move to 6th element of list, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 6th element and move to 7th element.
The negative values are only 2 and interval is only 1. So not counted as cycle.

Comment: Example 2: 
List(11,22,33,-25,-36,-43,20,25,28)
No. of cycles is 3.
Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 3th element, we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle
As we move to 4th element of list, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 4thelement and move to 5th, 6th element. we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle
As we move to 7th element of list, it is a positive value. So we start counting from 7th element and move to 8th, 9th element. we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. So one cycle

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul: yes, range is a RDD in the use case. It exactly looks like this range: Seq[com.Range] = List(XtreamRange(858,890,899,920,Start Engage,-758,-790,-890,-720,920,940,950))

Answer (score 2):

You can encode this "how many times it turns from negative to positive and stays positive for >= 2 seconds. If >= 2 seconds it is a cycle." pretty much directly into a pattern match with a guard. The expression `if(h < 0 && ht > 0 && hht > 0)` checks for a cycle and adds one to the result then continues with the rest of the list.

```
def countCycles(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
 case Nil => 0
 case h::ht::hht::t if(h < 0 && ht > 0 && hht > 0) => 1 + countCycles(t)
 case h::t => countCycles(t)
}

scala> countCycles(range)
res7: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner

```
range.sliding(3).count{case f::s::t::Nil => f < 0 && s > 0 && t > 0}
```

This generates all sub-sequences of length 3  and counts how many are -ve, +ve, +ve

Generalising cycle length

```
def countCycles(n:Int, xs:List[Int]) = xs.sliding(n+1)
                                         .count(ys => ys.head < 0 && ys.tail.forall(_ > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code would help you resolve you query.

```
object CycleCheck {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     var data3 = List(1, 4, 82, -2, -12, "startingpoint", -9, 32, 76,45, -98, 76, "Endpoint", -24)
     var data2 = data3.map(x => getInteger(x)).filter(_ != "unknown").map(_.toString.toInt)
     println(data2)
     var nCycle = findNCycle(data2)
     println(nCycle)
   }

   def getInteger(obj: Any) = obj match {
     case n: Int => obj
     case _     => "unknown"

   }
def findNCycle(obj: List[Int]) : Int = {
 var cycleCount =0
 var sign = ""
 var signCheck="+"
 var size = obj.size - 1
 var numberOfCycles=0
 var i=0
 for( x <- obj){
   if (x < 0){
     sign="-"
   }
   else if (x > 0){
     sign="+"
    }

  if(signCheck.equals(sign))
        cycleCount=cycleCount+1

  if(!signCheck.equals(sign) && cycleCount>1){
       cycleCount = 1
       numberOfCycles=numberOfCycles+1
  }    
  if(size==i && cycleCount>1)
      numberOfCycles= numberOfCycles+1


 if(cycleCount==1)
      signCheck = sign;

  i=i+1
 }

  return numberOfCycles
```

}
}