# Scala accessing list objects and evaluating number of cycles

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark

Scala accessing list objects and evaluating number of cycles

I have list of objects

```
case class ItemDesc(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int,e: Int, f: Int, g: Int desc: String)


val example = List(ItemDesc(6164,6165,6166,-6195,-6175,-6186,-6195, The values are correct), ItemDesc(14879,-14879,14879,-14894, 14879,14879,14894, The values are ok), ItemDesc(19682,-19690,-19682,19694,19690,19682,19694,The values are good),ItemDesc(5164,-5165,-5166,-6195,5165,5166,6195,The values are correct),ItemDesc(5879,5879,5879,5894,5879,5879,5879,The values are ok))
```

From the 'example' List, I want to access object 'ItemDesc'. And get the count of cycles. how many times it turns from negative to positive and stays positive for >= 2 seconds.

If >= 2 seconds it is a cycle.

**Example 1**: (6164,6165,6166,-6195,-6175,-6186,-6195, good)

No. of cycles is 2.

Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 3rd element, we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. Interval is >= 2. So it is one cycle. As we move to 3rd element of list to 4th element, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 4th element and move to 7th element and all elements have same negative sign. we had 3 intervals which means 3 seconds. Interval is >= 2. So it is one cycle. We start counting intervals fresh from zero as one number changes from positive to negative and vice-versa.

**Example 2**:  (14879,-14879,14879,-14894, 14879,14879,14894,better)

No. of cycles is 1.

Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 2nd element, the sign changes to negative. So we start counting the interval from zero. From element 2 to 3, the sign changes to negative. so interval counter is zero. From element 3 to 4, the sign changes to negative. interval counter is zero. From 5th to 7th all values have same sign, we had 2 intervals which means 2 seconds. Interval is >= 2. So it is one cycle.

**Example 3**: (5164,-5165,-5166,-6195,5165,5166,6195,good)

No. of cycles is 2

The below code which I wrote is not giving me the no. of cycles which I am looking for. Appreciate help in fixing it.

```
object findCycles {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

var numberOfPositiveCycles = 0
var numberOfNegativeCycles = 0
var numberOfCycles = 0

case class itemDesc(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, reason: String)

val example = List(ItemDesc(6164,6165,6166,-6195,-6175,-6186,-6195, The values are correct), ItemDesc(14879,-14879,14879,-14894, 14879,14879,14894, The values are ok), ItemDesc(19682,-19690,-19682,19694,19690,19682,19694,The values are good),ItemDesc(5164,-5165,-5166,-6195,5165,5166,6195,The values are correct),ItemDesc(5879,5879,5879,5894,5879,5879,5879,The values are ok))    

val data2 = example.map(x => getInteger(x)).filter(_ != "unknown").map(_.toString.toInt)
//println(data2)

     var nCycle = findNCycle(data2)
     println(nCycle)
   }

    def getInteger(obj: Any) = obj match {
    case n: Int => obj
    case _     => "unknown"
    }

   def findNCycle(obj: List[Int]) : Int = {      

    def NegativeCycles(fit: itemDesc): Int = {
    if (fit.a < 0 && fit.b < 0 && fit.c < 0) || if( fit.b < 0 && fit.c < 0 && fit.d < 0)
    {
      numberOfNegativeCycles += 1
    }
    }
    //println("negative cycle="+cycles)
    def PositiveCycles(fit: itemDesc): Int = {
      if (fit.a > 0 && fit.b > 0 && fit.c > 0) || if( fit.b > 0 && fit.c > 0 && fit.d > 0)
      {
        numberOfPositiveCycles += 1
      }
    }
    //println("positive cycle="+cycles)

    numberOfCycles = numberOfPositiveCycles + numberOfNegativeCycles
    return numberOfCycles 

  }
```

### }

For reference on the logic you can refer to- [Number of Cycles from list of values, which are mix of positives and negatives in Spark and Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219085/number-of-cycles-from-list-of-values-which-are-mix-of-positives-and-negatives-i)

Comment: Can you explain more how to count the cycles? How does example 1 have one cycle?

Comment: **Example 1**: (1,2,3,4,5,6,-15,-66, good)

 No. of cycles is 1.

 Reason: As we move from 1st element of list to 6th element, we had 5 intervals which means 5 seconds. So one cycle. As we move to 6th element of list, it is a negative value. So we start counting from 6th element and move to 7th element. The negative values are only 2 and interval is only 1. So not counted as cycle.

Comment: You should attempt to make your example code compile first.

Comment: Also, your examples in the text do not match your code. Should ItemDesc be case class ItemDesc(items: List[Int], description: String) to allow an arbitrary number of values as per examples? You also have a List of ItemDesc in your code sample, so do you expect a List of cycle counts? It looks like it since you are mapping over the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is rough but I think it does what you want. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do the split method.

I haven't used your ItemDesc as its simpler to demonstrate the problem given the examples you gave.

```
object CountCycles extends App {

  // No. of cycles is 1.
  val example1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -15, -66)

  // No. of cycles is 3.
  val example2 = List(11, 22, 33, -25, -36, -43, 20, 25, 28)

  // No. of cycles is 8
  val example3 = List(1, 4, 82, 5, 6, -2, -12, -22, -32, 100, 102, 100, 102, 0, 0, -2, -12, -22, -32, 4, 82, 5, 6, -6, 8, -6, -6, 8, 8, -5, -6, -7, 9, 8, 6, -5, -6, -7)

  def differentSign(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean =
    (x < 0) != ( y < 0)

  // return a list of sections
  def split(l: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] =
    l match {
      case Nil ⇒ Nil
      case h :: _ ⇒
        val transition: Int = l.indexWhere(differentSign(h, _))
        if (transition < 0) List(l)
        else {
          val (head, tail) = l.splitAt(transition)
          head :: split(tail)
        }
    }

  def count(l: List[Int]): Int = {
    val pos: List[List[Int]] = split(l)
    // count is the number of sections of length > 2
    pos.count(_.length > 2)
  }

  println(count(example1)) // 1
  println(count(example2)) // 3
  println(count(example3)) // 8
}
```

Comment: hi Walton, Thanks for the solution. Thanks helps to certain extent. But,If the values are a plain list, I developed a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219085/number-of-cycles-from-list-of-values-which-are-mix-of-positives-and-negatives-i. But my list has case class objects. I am not able to get solution for case class objects. The main question is now described in detail. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a working solution for the case where you have 7 items in the sample as shown in the description. If your case class changes and instead has a list of values then the implicit helper can be replaced with a simple call to the accessor

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object CyclesCounter extends App {

  val examples = List(
    ItemDesc(6164,6165,6166,-6195,-6175,-6186,-6195, "The values are correct"),
    ItemDesc(14879,-14879,14879,-14894, 14879,14879,14894, "The values are ok"),
    ItemDesc(19682,-19690,-19682,19694,19690,19682,19694,"The values are good"),
    ItemDesc(5164,-5165,-5166,-6195,5165,5166,6195,"The values are correct"),
    ItemDesc(5879,5879,5879,5894,5879,5879,5879,"The values are ok"))

  val counter = new CycleCounter

  // Add the index for more readable output
  examples.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (item, index) => println(s"Item at index $index has ${counter.cycleCount(item)} cycles")}
}

class CycleCounter {

  def cycleCount(item: ItemDesc): Int = {

  @tailrec
  def countCycles(remainingValues: List[Int], cycles: Int): Int = {
    if (remainingValues.isEmpty) cycles
    else {
      val headItems = {
        if (remainingValues.head < 0) remainingValues.takeWhile(_ < 0) 
        else remainingValues.takeWhile(_ >= 0)
      }

      val rest = remainingValues.drop(headItems.length)

      if (headItems.length > 2) countCycles(rest, cycles + 1) else countCycles(rest, cycles )
    }
  }

  countCycles(item, 0)
}

// Helper to convert ItemDesc into a List[Int] for easier processing
implicit def itemToValueList(item: ItemDesc): List[Int] = List(item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d, item.e, item.f, item.g)

}

case class ItemDesc(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, reason: String)
```

Output from running:

```
Item at index 0 has 2 cycles
Item at index 1 has 1 cycles
Item at index 2 has 1 cycles
Item at index 3 has 2 cycles
Item at index 4 has 1 cycles
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As i read, i see that your problem is to treat the case class as a single entity and no as a list of elements and a reason. I would change the case class to one of these alternatives, first one is if the amount of elements is static (4 in this case):

```
case class ItemDesc(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, reason: String) {
    lazy val getAsList = List(a,b,c,d)
  }

ItemDesc(1,2,3,4,"reason").getAsList
```

In the second case, it can be used if the amount of elements is unbounded:

```
case class ItemDescAlt(reason:String, elements: Int*)

ItemDescAlt("reason", 5164,-5165,-5166,-6195,5165,5166,6195)
```

And like the rest i will give my custom version for calculate the number of cycles:

```
def getCycles(list: Seq[Int]): Int = {
    def headPositive(list: Seq[Int]): Boolean = {
      list.headOption.forall(_ >= 0)
    }
    val result = list.foldLeft((0, 0, !headPositive(list))) { //we start with a symbol diferent to the firs one
      case ((numberOfCycles, cycleLength, lastWasPositive), number) => { //for each element...
        val numberSign = number >= 0
        val actualCycleLength = if (numberSign == lastWasPositive) { //see if the actual simbol is equal to the last one
          cycleLength + 1 //in that case the length is increased
        } else {
          0 //in the other reset it
        }
        val actualNCycles = if (actualCycleLength == 2) { //if the actual length is equal to to
          numberOfCycles + 1 //it is a proper new cycle
        } else {
          numberOfCycles // no new cycles
        }
        (actualNCycles, actualCycleLength, numberSign) //return the actual state
      }
    }
    result._1 //get the final number of cycles
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a solution for `List`, you can convert any case class into a List using `productIterator`:

```
scala> case class X(a:Int, b:Int, c:String)
defined class X

scala> val x = X(1,2,"a")
x: X = X(1,2,a)

scala> x.productIterator.toList
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, a)
```

The main problem is that you get back a `List[Any]` so you might have to do more work to get a `List[Int]`